# Creating a LVM storage with python

Tags: python, xen, lvm

I am trying to make a script with python to duplicate VMs however I am getting the following error:

```
sudo lvcreate -L3072 -s -n TestPrestashop1-disk /dev/ls2018-vg/Prestashop-disk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VMDuplicator.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "VMDuplicator.py", line 62, in main
    createLV(True, amount)
  File "VMDuplicator.py", line 37, in createLV
    output = call(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

my code:

```
#create a new LVM storage and duplicate the prestashop disk into it and name it Prestashop[i]-disk / swap
def createLV(swap, amount):
    i = 1
    if(swap == False):
        while(i < int(amount)):
            try:
                output = subprocess.check_output(["sudo lvcreate -L3072 -s -n TestPrestashop" + str(i) + " -disk /dev/ls2018-vg/Prestashop-disk"])
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
                return False
            i += 1
        return true
    elif(swap == True):
        while(i < int(amount)):
            try:
                s = "sudo lvcreate -L3072 -s -n TestPrestashop" + str(i) + "-disk /dev/ls2018-vg/Prestashop-disk"
                print(s)
                output = call(s)
                #output = subprocess.check_output(["sudo lvcreate -L3072 -s -n TestPrestashop" + str(i) + "-disk /dev/ls2018-vg/Prestashop-disk"])
                #output = subprocess.check_output([s])
                #output = subprocess.check_output(["sudo lvcreate -L3072 -s -n TestPrestashop" + str(i) + "-swap /dev/ls2018-vg/Prestashop-swap"])
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
                return False
            i += 1
        return True
```

Does anyone know if this is the right way to use the function call or subprocess in python? Because it works fine with the ls -l command for example.

I also print out the command that is executed, namely: sudo lvcreate -L3072 -s -n TestPrestashop1-disk /dev/ls2018-vg/Prestashop-disk (in variable S). If I manually execute the command it works just fine... Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it with an os.system call.

Comment: Which one? What code did you use? This does not follow the [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) format and it doesn't help users. :-/